# Click listener is not working on surface view inside frame layout

Tags: android, surfaceview, onitemclicklistener, agora.io

I have read out many questions but I don't get the answer to mine.
So I am posting this new question.

I am working on a live streaming app. Basically I want to change the surface view size on click event like Whatsapp video calling.
I have two scenarios:-
Scenario 1:-  One is relative layout which contains a surface view and there is a frame layout which also contains a surface view and I want to exchange when click event happens but the Click event listener is not working.
XML file

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/liveStreaming_videoAndControlsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black">

        <com.sos.GD_Live.utils.liveUtils.VideoGridContainer
            android:id="@+id/liveStreaming_videoContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </com.sos.GD_Live.utils.liveUtils.VideoGridContainer>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/videoChat_localVideoRender"
            android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:onClick="frameclick"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            />
```

Its parent layout is also a frame layout

```
public class VideoGridContainer extends RelativeLayout implements Runnable {
    private static final int MAX_USER = 4;
    private static final int STAT_LEFT_MARGIN = 34;
    private static final int STAT_TEXT_SIZE = 10;

    private SparseArray<ViewGroup> mUserViewList = new SparseArray<>(MAX_USER);
    private List<Integer> mUidList = new ArrayList<>(MAX_USER);
    private Handler mHandler;
    private int mStatMarginBottom;
    private VideoViewEventListener mEventListener;
    public VideoGridContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public VideoGridContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public VideoGridContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mHandler = new Handler(getContext().getMainLooper());
    }

    public void addUserVideoSurface(int uid, SurfaceView surface, boolean isLocal) {
        if (surface == null) {
            return;
        }

        int id = -1;
        if (isLocal) {
            if (mUidList.contains(0)) {
                mUidList.remove((Integer) 0);
                mUserViewList.remove(0);
            }

            if (mUidList.size() == MAX_USER) {
                mUidList.remove(0);
                mUserViewList.remove(0);
            }
            id = 0;
        } else {
            if (mUidList.contains(uid)) {
                mUidList.remove((Integer) uid);
                mUserViewList.remove(uid);
            }

            if (mUidList.size() < MAX_USER) {
                id = uid;
            }
        }

        if (id == 0) mUidList.add(0, uid);
        else mUidList.add(uid);

        if (id != -1) {
            mUserViewList.append(uid, createVideoView(surface));

            requestGridLayout();
        }
    }

    private ViewGroup createVideoView(SurfaceView surface) {
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());

        layout.setId(surface.hashCode());

        LayoutParams videoLayoutParams =
                new LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layout.addView(surface, videoLayoutParams);

        TextView text = new TextView(getContext());
        text.setId(layout.hashCode());
        LayoutParams textParams =
                new LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        textParams.bottomMargin = mStatMarginBottom;
        textParams.leftMargin = STAT_LEFT_MARGIN;
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        text.setTextSize(STAT_TEXT_SIZE);

        layout.addView(text, textParams);
        return layout;
    }

    public void removeUserVideo(int uid, boolean isLocal) {
        if (isLocal && mUidList.contains(0)) {
            mUidList.remove((Integer) 0);
            mUserViewList.remove(0);
        } else if (mUidList.contains(uid)) {
            mUidList.remove((Integer) uid);
            mUserViewList.remove(uid);
        }

        requestGridLayout();

        if (getChildCount() == 0) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
        }
    }

    private void requestGridLayout() {
        removeAllViews();
        layout(mUidList.size());
    }

    private void layout(int size) {
        LayoutParams[] params = getParams(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            addView(mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(i)), params[i]);
        }
    }

    private LayoutParams[] getParams(int size) {
        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();

        LayoutParams[] array =
                new LayoutParams[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                array[0] = new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[0].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            } else if (i == 1) {
                array[1] = new LayoutParams(width, height / 2);
                array[0].height = array[1].height;
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(0)).getId());
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            } else if (i == 2) {
                array[i] = new LayoutParams(width / 2, height / 2);
                array[i - 1].width = array[i].width;
                array[i].addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(i - 1)).getId());
                array[i].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(i - 1)).getId());
            } else if (i == 3) {
                array[i] = new LayoutParams(width / 2, height / 2);
                array[0].width = width / 2;
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 0);
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(0)).getId());
                array[1].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[2].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                array[2].addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 0);
                array[2].addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, 0);
                array[2].addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(0)).getId());
                array[3].addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(1)).getId());
                array[3].addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, mUserViewList.get(mUidList.get(2)).getId());
            }
        }

        return array;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        clearAllVideo();
    }

    private void clearAllVideo() {
        removeAllViews();
        mUserViewList.clear();
        mUidList.clear();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
    public void setItemEventHandler(VideoViewEventListener listener) {
        this.mEventListener = listener;
    }
}
```

This code where in Java file, when I added surface view for both of the layouts

```
mVideoLayout = findViewById(R.id.liveStreaming_videoContainer);
mVideoLayout.addUserVideoSurface(0, surface, true);
SurfaceView surface = prepareRtcVideo(remotehost, false);
        surface.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
        mCameraBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        remotehostlist.add(remotehost);
        surface.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            surface.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    Toast.makeText(LiveStreamingActivity.this, "it's good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
            surface.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(LiveStreamingActivity.this, "it's good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        });

        mLayoutSmallView.addView(surface);
        mLayoutSmallView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLayoutSmallView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                Toast.makeText(LiveStreamingActivity.this, "Focus changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        mRtcEngine.setupLocalVideo(new VideoCanvas(surface, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_HIDDEN, 0));
        mRtcEngine.enableVideo();
```

I have already tried onclick in XML, ontouchlistener, onfocuschange listener. But no one of them is working for it. Also tried is focusable.
The problem is I am unable to click the frame layout named mLayoutSmallView.
I want to switch the surface views when it is clicked.

Comment: (Do you intend to disclose information about the other scenario?)

Comment: I tagged agora because The surface views are added by using agora. One is for local surface view and second one is for remote surface view.

Comment: Hey @MamtaRana, is there a reason you are not able to attach a touch/click listener to the frame layout instead of the surface view?

Comment: I have tried to attach the touch/click listener to frame layout instead of surface view but I am not having success in that also. I have no idea why I am unable to attach any click and touch listener to frame layout as well as surface view

Comment: You can try listening for the event outside the UI thread and launch the toast inside the UI thread. This seems more like an issue with the way you are attaching the listener to the framelayout. There's an official example by Agora that sets a click listener. You can take a look here: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Android-UIKit/blob/8c7c206197d1ae7b21af3d186067a6bf1b490d3d/agorauikit_android/src/main/java/io/agora/agorauikit_android/AgoraVideoViewer%2BOrdering.kt#L208